# How can i internationalize Django HTML Templates using App Engine with python?

Tags: python, django, google-app-engine, internationalization, django-templates

I am writing a web site http://www.perlesloyfer.no that will use

`country = self.request.headers.get('X-AppEngine-Country')` to determine if its a norwegian 
visitor or one from another language.
The template is shown using

```
path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'index.html')
self.response.out.write(template.render(path, template_values))
```

If visitor is from another country, it should show the HTML templates internationalized to english, else they should be on norwegian like it is now.

Should i make separate html templates for each language, or is it a way to make one template and just get strings from different files with Django?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Django has a decent [i18n feature](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/i18n/). Please just use it. As a side note, using X-AppEngine-Country to determine the content language is a bad idea (don't forget people abroad).